# Plotting numbers against a WPF graph?

Tags: c#, wpf, graph

I'm trying to plot a series of numbers against a graph.

A **really** simple use case scenario. Just grab a number plot it, after n seconds, grab the same variable, if it has changed plot it again, and so on and so forth.

I've downloaded the WPF Toolkit from CodePlex but I can't find any documentation for the GraphControl control,  or even a method like, AddItem() or something like that.

Here's my XAML and C# code:

```
<GroupBox Header="Timechart" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Verdana" Height="211" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,88,0,0" Name="groupBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="479">
    <my:GraphControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="491,299,0,0" x:Name="graphControl1" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
</GroupBox>


private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SharpDream.Api.Concrete.XmlMemberFinder x = new XmlMemberFinder();
    var user = x.FindMember(335389);
    textBox1.Text = user.Reputation;
    graphControl1.
}
```

Does anyone know to do this basic use case? Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple XAML-only chart to get you started:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <PointCollection x:Key="sampleData">
            <Point X="1" Y="6"/>
            <Point X="2" Y="4"/>
            <Point X="3" Y="8"/>
        </PointCollection>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <chartingToolkit:Chart Title="Chart Title">
        <chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries Name="chart1" Title="Column Series" ItemsSource="{StaticResource sampleData}" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding X}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Y}"/>
    </chartingToolkit:Chart>
</Grid>
```

You can download samples of all the supported WPF chart types from this blog:

- [WPF Charting: It's official! June 2009 release of the WPF Toolkit is now available!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/06/25/wpf-charting-it-s-official-june-2009-release-of-the-wpf-toolkit-is-now-available.aspx)

Download the **DataVisualizationDemos** sample.